# Complete list of font color for Jupyter Notebook markdown cells?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

With this command in Jupyter Notebook, I can make markdown cells of a different color:

```
<font color='red'>some colored text</font>
```

What is the complete list of the available colors? From trial and error, there seems to be quite a number, but how can I know which ones are available?

Comment: I believe it's just converted to CSS, no? So any valid CSS color should apply.

Comment: Yup. Well, strictly it is not CSS and non-standard; there is no modern standard defining the `font` behaviour so browser vendors can accept whatever they like. I would guess that there are some valid CSS colors that would not work in some browsers in `<font>` tags. But yeah, the gist is Jupyter is not controlling the colors. In JupyterLab the markdown cells are passed to marked.js and rendered as HTML after sanitization. Using `<span style="color: red">text</span>` is more predictable (and there is an answer for that one, which is "any valid CSS color").

Comment: I don't know CSS tho

Comment: For web-related topics MDN is a good place to start: see [possible color values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) and [overview of `color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color), unless you prefer reading the actual spec, like [CSS Color Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-css-color-3-20180619/).